Sort specific Google Sheets by one Column on call
I have quite a big Google Sheets file (spreadsheet) with 15+ sheets.
I need a script that lets me sort some of the spreadsheets with a call of the function/button whatever by a specific column for example:
Spreadsheet "Employees" and "Teams" sort by column 2
All other data should be sorted like a normal Google filter sort.
All scripts I have found only support sort by the active Spreadsheet.

What do you mean by a "normal google filter sort"? Do you mean sort by the first column of data? Also, if you could provide some of your spreadsheets/data that would be helpful, even if its mock data and not the real thing, to improve understanding of what you need. Also, to clarify, are you trying to sort different spreadsheet files, or different sheets within one file?

So here is one option you can try.  It is just a basic script which will sort the active sheet based on the column specified in the prompt. (It could be modified to select sheet by name and then sort by column, but a typo would result in an invalid argument).  That is why I would recommend to run off the active sheet.
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('')
      .addItem('Sort by Column', 'displayPrompt')
      .addToUi();
}

function displayPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Select column to sort by:");
  
  //Get the button that the user pressed.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var colResp = result.getResponseText();
  var colNum = Number(colResp);
  if (button === ui.Button.OK) {
    sortBy(colNum);
  } else if (button === ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    Logger.log("The user clicked the [X] button and closed the prompt dialog."); 
  }
    
}


function sortBy(colNum) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var rg=sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()+1,sheet.getLastColumn()+1);
  rg.sort([{column:colNum,ascending:true}]);//The sort options is an array of objects but the array can be left for just one.
}

Note:  There are no validations put into place.  If a user puts "yes" in the box, an error will be returned with something like:  "Reference is out of range."  If you wish, an error handler could be added to the script.
This will give you a custom menu item when you open/refresh the spreadsheet:

You will have to authorize the script the first time you run the function from the menu.  Note that the script will not run the first time when you authorize it.  It will run every time after that, though.

nice looking script and thanks for your work but i couldnt get the script to work (i authorized it) but no input worked.
i made an example sheet to visualize my problem (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BdhKO7dnOUKK_0rPKpY6OQYmXZ04SJ8Oe48mAK1V-LQ/edit?usp=sharing)
it would be great if i could sort specific sheets (there are completly different others) by Colum B (like pressing the Arrow in B3) with one button press

Is this how your sheet is laid out?  Are your headers on Line 3? If so, change this line: var rg=sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()+1,sheet.getLastColumn()+1); to var rg=sheet.getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow()+1,sheet.getLastColumn()+1);

Otherwise can you share a sample sheet of how your data is actually laid out?

sry cant do this cause of sensitive information but my provided sheet has the same structure (Headers in Line 3 and i need sorting by column B)
still not sure what i need to write in the box (sheetname, Column Number, column Name)

I was just wondering if the sheet is laid out the same.  So, first you need to modify the code per my first comment.  Then in the box, on the sheet you want sorted, write in the column number.
